# ViewController (Width and Height) scale

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I want to set a screen size for my view (Making it for iPhone 6). Problem is, I don't know if the input scale in point or pixel

Is it 600 pixel or 600 point?

[image]

Thank

Answer (score 2):

It is in `point`. In `retina` devices, 1 `point` equals two `pixels` (or 1 `point` equals `three` pixels for @3x supported device). In `non-retina` devices, 1 `points` equals 1 `pixel`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **these are points, not pixels.**

I am not sure why you want to set a fixed size only for iPhone but I think you might be interested in checking out some [Auto Layout tutorials like this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2). It will help you build interfaces for multiple devices at a time !

Like KDeogharkar said, there are different factor between points and pixel depending on the device. **Usually you don't want to work with pixels.**